# Print title of block group to allow for collapsible group

Tags: blocks

Currently I am working on a site where I need groups of blocks which should be collapsible. The blocks are grouped by using block group module. For the collapsible part I am using collapsiblock. 
By default the block group is rendered in a simple div, which I change by applying a template to add the title. But the title is not available as a variable, because block group module uses the title field only for administration and thus the $title variables are all empty.

Does anybody know how to access the variable in a template file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm about to do something similar, but I imagine you could do a preprocess and populate the variable yourself.

-- EDIT --

As a matter of fact, I am sure of it. Just did it myself.

In template.php write a hook_preprocess_region() function.

```
function mytheme_preprocess_region(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['region'] == 'blockgroup_regionname') {
    $variables['title'] = 'Title';
  }
}
```

Then just in your template.

```
<?php if ($title): ?>
  <h2 class="title"><?php print $title; ?></h2>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Which in turn should make the variable available to whatever else you are trying to do. SHOULD anyway. Good luck!